# C++ Unwanted implicit conversion in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a simple situation where I have some uniform interface, such as this:

```
class I {
public:
    virtual void Run() = 0;
};
```

I have some templates that have the same interface but do not declare it virtual, for performance reasons. So I need to add one more layer that makes their function virtual:

```
template <class B>
class S : public I {
    B mb;

public:
    S(B b)
        :mb(b)
    {}

    virtual void Run()
    {
        std::cout << mb << std::endl; // or mb.Run()
    }
};
```

Note that I replaced `mb.Run()` by printing its value. That is only for simplification, it does not affect the behavior I'm encountering here. But anyway, so far so good. Now to make things convenient, I have one more class that makes the interface automatically:

```
class A {
    I *mi;

public:
    A()
        :mi(0)
    {}

    template <class B>
    A(B b)
        :mi(new S<B>(b))
    {}

    A(A &a)
        :mi(a.mi)
    {
        a.mi = 0;
    }

    template <class B>
    A &operator =(B b)
    {
        delete mi;
        mi = new S<B>(b);
        return *this;
    }

    A &operator =(A &a)
    {
        delete mi;
        mi = a.mi;
        a.mi = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    I *operator ->()
    {
        assert(mi);
        return mi;
    }
};
```

This acts as an automatic constructor of `S` and also as a simple managed pointer at the same time. I would use it as follows:

```
A a = instanceOfB();
```

That should call the template `A::A<instanceOfB>()` which in turn allocates a new `S<instanceOfB>` on heap and stores it in an `A`. Now I can call `A->Run()` which finally resolves to `S->Run()` and that would call `instanceOfB::Run()`, which is not virtual.

Instead what happens is that `instanceOfB()` gets first converted to `A` and then it dies, as there is no constructor that would take `A` (only `A&`). Note that this only happens in g++, Visual Studio 2008 and Visual C++ 6.0 both compile the code without problems. You can reproduce the behavior using:

```
void Test()
{
    A a = 4; // error: no matching function for call to "A::A(A)"
    //A a; a = 4; // works
    //A a(4); // works
    a->Run();
}
```

I have tried declaring the constructors as explicit, but that doesn't seem to help or I may be doing it wrong. If `A` was not managing the pointer, I could take value of `const A&` in constructor, so the whole problem would be solved. Is there another solution to this problem? C++11 is unfortunately NOT available.

I'm trying to implement efficient delegates. Basically I want to be able to do:

```
int myFunction(int, float);
StaticCallCtx<int, MakeTypelist(int, float)> ctx = Grab(&myFunction)(1, 2.3f);

// ctx.Run() calls the function, with the specified arguments
// it's *not* virtual (compiles to just a few instructions so I
// don't want to spoil it by adding a vfptr)

AutoCallPointer p = ctx;
// or directly AutoCallPointer p = Grab(&myFunction)(1, 2.3f);
// wraps StaticCallCtx, has ->Run() as well, this time there
// is the price of calling the virtual function
```

Ultimately, high performance (this will later serve for acceleration of some linear algebra functions) and user comfort (short `AutoCallPointer p = Grab(fun)(parms)` without writing template argument lists) are the main goals here.

**EDIT**:

The solution of @ecatmur is correct. As it is quite short, I will attempt to reiterate here. g++ correctly refuses to compile the code, as in `A` there is no copy-constructor that will take `A` (only `A&`). The template constructor will **not** be used in the case of copy initialization `A a = instanceOfB()`.

We must provide a copy-constructor, taking `const A&`. Because of copy elision, a declaration of the constructor without a body is sufficient. This is however not a nice workarround.

It is better to declare the `A::mi` as `mutable` and change the existing `A&` constructor to take `const A&` (the copy-operator may also be changed). The fixed `A` looks like this:

```
class A {
    mutable I *mi;

public:
    A()
        :mi(0)
    {}

    template <class B>
    A(B b)
        :mi(new S<B>(b))
    {}

    A(const A &a)
        :mi(a.mi)
    {
        a.mi = 0;
    }

    template <class B>
    A &operator =(B b)
    {
        delete mi;
        mi = new S<B>(b);
        return *this;
    }

    A &operator =(const A &a)
    {
        delete mi;
        mi = a.mi;
        a.mi = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    I *operator ->()
    {
        assert(mi);
        return mi;
    }
};
```

This code compiles in both g++ and Microsoft's compilers (also in http://codepad.org/9FqUk0Fj).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `A(A&& a)`...

Comment: IIRC the explicit keyword was designed for this case, are you sure you placed it correctly?

Comment: @gbjbaanb Well, that's what I thought. Where should I put it? I tried before the constructors or before the parameter-less constructor but that did not cut it.

Comment: Its been years since I needed it - but [here's an example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)

Comment: @gbjbaanb Yes, that does not help (see http://codepad.org/eSZyw4ZY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy-initialize an object of class type, the copy constructor needs to be available, even if the copy is elided.  g++ is correct to reject your program; your older versions of MSVC are incorrect to accept it.

You may be able to provide a declaration of a copy constructor without a definition, on the basis that calls to it will be elided or otherwise fail at link time.  This could be somewhat confusing, though.

The most obvious solution is to use direct-initialization, which as you have already observed works fine.

Comment: I was sure it was Microsoft's fault all along somehow. Is there any chance that the body-less copy-constructor will actually be used by the program? Wouldn't it be better to actually provide a body, which would const-cast the argument and remove the managed pointer from its ownership? What are the chance of that causing some memory problems?

Comment: @theswine there's no guarantee a copy will actually be elided for copy-initialization etc., although the non-`const` reference constructor will be preferred where both are admissible.  A `const_cast` is fine if you can guarantee that the source object is a temporary; it becomes illegal if the source object is physically const (i.e. declared with `const`).

Comment: It occurred to me that I can declare the pointer field as mutable and then the cast is unnecessary. It probably solves most, if not all of my problems.